# Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence an $L$ a real number such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded

This reminds me of the bounded monotone convergence theorem (BMCT) but in reverse. So I was thinking of proving by somehow reversing the proof of the BMCT. Am I approaching this correct? And are there alternative ways of doing this that may be simpler?

Comment: Why the downvote everybody?

Comment: @BrianMScott this is not a duplicate, I am talking about a particular way of doing this problem...

Answer (score 5):

Take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-L|<1$ for $n\ge N$ and let
$$M=\max\{|a_1|,\ldots,|a_N|,L+1\}.$$

Comment: So my reverse BMCT won't work?

Comment: and what is M and how am I supposed to use M?